# Trapezoid ABCD,AB=7,BC=CD=4, moving point X is on DH, moving Point P is on XB which CP is vertical to XB.What is the minimum value of AP?

Tags: geometry

Trapezoid ABCD,AB=7,BC=CD=4, moving point X is on DH, moving Point P is on XB which CP is vertical to XB.What is the minimum value of AP?

I know triangle CPB is similar to triangle BMX.
I think the minimum value of AP is when point X is on point D,but I don’t know how to prove it.

Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B, P, C form a circle with diamter = BC = 4; radius = 2; N as the center located  at the midpoint of BC. Let AN cut the circle at P'. Then AP' will be the shortest.

[image]

AB touches that circle at B.

With AB = 7, by power of a point, $7^2 = AP'(AP'')$. AP' will be the shortest when AP'' is the longest. and the longest is AP' + 4.

The shortest length is $\sqrt {2^2 + 7^2} - 2$